# Replace 'D' to 'E' within scientific notation for all values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have an output file from old fortran code, which outputs values as double precision. Therefore any numbers given in scientific notation are in the form 1.23D+4 for example. I'm saving this csv as a pandas dataframe and with to do data analysis.

I'm looking for a way to convert the D to an E within every entry within the dataframe, `dedx`. I've tried:

```
for c in dedx.columns: 
    for i in dedx[c]:
            if isinstance(i, str):
                i = float(i.replace('D', 'E'))
```

This changes the value within the loop, as can be seen using print(i) but does not make changes to the actual dataframe.

A sample of the dataframe is shown below:

```
ENERGY(MEV) DE/DX(MEV/MM)   DE/DX(MEV.CM2/MG)   RANGE(MM) RANGE(MG/CM2)
0   0.01    4.908059D+01    4.811823D-02    0.000477    0.486766
1   0.50    4.917734D+02    4.821308D-01    0.002121    2.162930
2   1.00    5.261802D+02    5.158630D-01    0.003088    3.149690
3   1.50    5.105083D+02    5.004984D-01    0.004050    4.130490
4   2.00    4.842530D+02    4.747579D-01    0.005054    5.155440
5   2.50    4.568363D+02    4.478788D-01    0.006117    6.239750
6   3.00    4.309473D+02    4.224973D-01    0.007245    7.389450
7   3.50    4.072914D+02    3.993053D-01    0.008438    8.607170
8   4.00    3.859186D+02    3.783516D-01    0.009700    9.894000
9   4.50    3.666619D+02    3.594725D-01    0.011030    11.250200
10  5.00    3.492947D+02    3.424458D-01    0.012427    12.675800
11  5.50    3.335896D+02    3.270486D-01    0.013892    14.170300
12  6.00    3.193387D+02    3.130772D-01    0.015425    15.733200
13  6.50    3.063596D+02    3.003526D-01    0.017024    17.364200
14  7.00    2.944946D+02    2.887202D-01    0.018689    19.062500
15  7.50    2.836086D+02    2.780477D-01    0.020419    20.827500
16  8.00    2.735860D+02    2.682215D-01    0.022215    22.658800
17  8.50    2.643277D+02    2.591448D-01    0.024074    24.555600
18  9.00    2.557488D+02    2.507341D-01    0.025998    26.517400
19  9.50    2.477762D+02    2.429178D-01    0.027984    28.543700
20  10.00   2.403466D+02    2.356339D-01    0.030033    30.633900
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, `str.replace` creates *a new string* that is not the same as the one in the dataframe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I assumed, if within the loop I put i=new_value, the old string would be overwritten?

Comment: That's only assigning to the *local variable* `i`, it doesn't impact `dedx` at all.

Comment: How do you read the old fortran output file in pandas? Do you use `pandas.read_csv`?

Comment: @Valentino, yes the file is read using pandas.read_csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this kind of conversion while reading the file with `pandas.read_csv` rather than looping. It is more efficient.

```
d_to_e = lambda x : float(x.replace('D', 'E'))

df = pd.read_csv('yourfilename.csv', converters={'DE/DX(MEV/MM)' : d_to_e, 'DE/DX(MEV.CM2/MG)' : d_to_e})
```

The `converters` parameter allows you to apply a function to the data of each column. The result is stored in the dataframe. `converters` takes a dict with column names and functions to be applied to each column data.
I defined the function `d_to_e` which does the letter replacement and return a float as you did in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (to replace your whole code):

```py
dedx[c]=dedx[c].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace("D", "E")) if isinstance(x, str))
```

(assuming `dedx[c]` is reference to dataframe column, that you want to modify)

Comment: I have just tried this code and I am getting a 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' error message.

Comment: hm, and what would be c for you then ? (so one step before your code) - try for c="DE/DX(MEV.CM2/MG)" for example